# getting a generalized binary incrementer bit by bit

Tags: python

A binary incrementer bit by bit is a sequence in which each succesive nuber is reached by changing only one bit from predecessor, in a way it travels from 0 to 2^n reaching all values without repetition.

An example is the 4-bit incrementer:

```py
#python
incrementer4=(3,2,3,1,3,2,3,0,1,3,2,3,1,3,2)
pins=[0]*4
def change(p,i):
    p[i]=0 if p[i] else 1

print(pins)
for i in incrementer4:
    change(pins,i)
    print(pins)
```

Is there a way to generalise the incrementer4 for any n?
I mean I need a function `getIncrementer(int n)` where n is power of 2

This is for an electronic projet so I can send the conmuter one pin change each time and optimize the reading time.

Comment: You seem to be describing a *Gray code*.  There are various modules and example programs available for dealing with them in Python.

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me to this! I didn't even know there was a name for this problem. Anyway, here it is the python solution 

<code>
    def _gray(n):
      if n == 1:
        return [0, 1]
      else:
        p = _gray(n-1)
        pr = [x + (1<<(n-1)) for x in p[::-1]]
        return p + pr

    n=1<<2
    for i in [("0"*n + bin(a)[2:])[-n:] for a in _gray(n)]:
      print(i) 
</code>